# Closure Compiler Java API escape URL entities

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to compile a lot of JS file using Closure Compiler Java API, but it escapes these characters in string literals `<>&=` although it's not the case when it's called from command line.

```
CompilerOptions options = new CompilerOptions();
options.setLanguageIn(ECMASCRIPT5);
options.setLanguageOut(ECMASCRIPT5);
options.setOutputCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(options);

SourceFile extern = SourceFile.fromCode("externs.js", "");
SourceFile input = SourceFile.fromCode("input.js", "'<a>'");

Compiler compiler = new Compiler();
compiler.compile(extern, input, options);
System.out.println(compiler.toSource());
```

This is the output:

```
"\x3ca\x3e";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by testing every CompilerOptions options:

```
options.setTrustedStrings(true);
```